# Wicked gem, how create dynamic template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, dynamic, wicked-gem

I am  using wick for a multi step form, steps are created dynamiquement like this:

```
  include Wicked::Wizard
  before_action :set_steps
  before_action :setup_wizard

  def set_steps
    self.steps = Answer.pluck(:cached_slug)
  end
```

So far so good, but how can I create the templates for each step, since they are defined dynamically?
I did not put any examples because I have no idea what to do!

Comment: do you mean Wicked gem?

Comment: Yesss, :-p, sorry